# Ajax submit form doesn't work in online mode

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, submit

This code doesn't work in "online" mode but is working in "localhost"... Can anybody help me? Console doesn't show an error.

```
function contactForm() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'main.php',
    data: {
      name: $(".js-contact-name").text(),
      email: $(".js-contact-email").text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").replace(/\s+/g, " "),
      subject: $(".js-contact-subject").text(),
      message: $(".js-contact-brief").text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ")},
      success: function (responseText) {                
        $(".js-mail-message").addClass("js-hidden");
        $(".js-contact-submit").addClass("js-hidden");
        $(".js-mail-success").removeClass("js-hidden")
        console.log(responseText);
      },
      async: true
    });
    return false;
  })
}
```

Comment: I've also tried with async: false

Comment: go in networks tab in inspect element and see the url and status of the request

Comment: 504, Connectionkeep-aliveContent-Typetext/htmlDateSat, 04 Mar 2017 17:11:37 GMTKeep-Alivetimeout=15ServernginxTransfer-Encodingchunked

Comment: You can try with `/main.php`

Comment: you can try with '/main.php' or './main.php' in url of ajax request

Comment: I have tried with "./main.php", "/main.php" and "complete url" and the result is the same, the response header remains loading and finally returns 504

Comment: im getting this answer:
<html>
<head>
<title>The page is temporarily unavailable</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white" text="black">
    <table width="100%" height="100%">
    <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
    The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.<br/>
    Please try again later.
    <br />
    3a1e03e9dcb241085cb03a68bd28c186
    4392589f97c3fb3b1f5ca754aebd1fe3
    beb046373c3087252ade08846b5e4ca2
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: @ManuelRamos Have you added the jQuery lib script to the from?  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

According to the hosting provider in which the project to which this code belongs, the server configuration did not support requests, ajax.